# Keep values in data frame= Na (sodium in chemistry) as is

Tags: r, dataframe, na, sodium

### Original df (clinical chemistry)

```
Subject Code Test Value Units   Flag
1       NA    NA   147   mmol/L    
2       NA/K  NA/K 10.5  RATIO  
3       K     K    4.7   mmol/L 
4       CK    CK   235   UL
...
```

### Ideal df after cleaning

```
Subject Code  Test             Value  Units   Flag
1       NA    Sodium           147   mmol/L   NA
2       NA/K  Sodium Potassium 10.5  RATIO    NA
3       K     Potassium        4.7   mmol/L   NA
4       CK    Creatine Kinase  235    UL      NA
...
```

### What I have tried

```
df <- read.csv(file="clinchemistry.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$df[df8$Test == "NA"] <- "Sodium"

df$df[df8$Code == "NA"] <- "Sodium"
```

and

```
df[is.na(lb$Code)]<-"Sodium"

lb[is.na(lb$Code)]<-"Sodium"
```

**RESULTS:**

All the sodium values disappear or get an error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(lb$Tesst), value = "Sodium")
>   :    duplicate subscripts for columns

**WOULD SOMEONE GUIDE MY THINKING?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `na.strings=""`

```
 df <- read.csv(file="clinchemistry.csv", 
     na.strings="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

(omitting arguments that are set to their default values)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want, depending on what it is that you want ;)

First I create a minimal example data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = 1:4,
                 Code = c(NA, "NA/K", "K", "CK"),
                 Test = c(NA, NA ,"K", "CR"))
```

Now, if for some reason your Sodium values are stored as `NA` (the missing value, not the string `"NA" you could do this (you really need an excellent reason to replace NAs, because in most cases this is going to be invented data. But your reason might be a valid one ;) :

```
# Replace missing values NA with string "Sodium"
# 
df$Code_fixed[is.na(df$Code)] <- "Sodium"
```

Or if you have a string `"NA"` that you want to change "Sodium"

```
# Replace string "NA" with string "Sodium"
# 
df$Code_fixed[df$Code == "NA"] <- "Sodium"
```

Or if you want to exchange the character combination "NA" in a string

```
# Replace any occurence of string "NA" with string "Sodium"
# 
df$Code_fixed <- gsub("NA", "Sodium", df$Code)
```

Do all of the above:

```
# First initialize vector with characters already replaced
df$Code_fixed <- gsub("NA", "Sodium", df$Code)
df$Code_fixed[is.na(df$Code_fixed)] <- "Sodium"
```