# R changes my list of character strings with "na" into the words as missing values (ex : BDNA3 --> NA) - How to deal with this?

Tags: r, character, na

I am struggling with R since 2 days without finding any solution !

Here is my problem :

- I have a list of symbols extracted from one data-frame : `annotation$"SYMBOL"`
- I would like to bind it to another data-frame, called "matrix", and to assign them as rownames.
- I extracted the column, bound it without problems. However, I realized that once this was done, changing them into rownames doesn't work because ~ 5000 genes / 15000 are then changed as "NA"
- I realize that actually it's all the genes with "NA" in their symbol that are seen as "missing values"
- I try to change them `as.character(annotation$"SYMBOL")` but that doesn't change....

HERE:

```
X=as.character(annotation$"SYMBOL")

summary(X)
   Length     Class      Mode 
    16978 character character  
unique (unlist (lapply (as.character(annotation$"SYMBOL"), function (x) which (is.na (x))))) 
[1] 1
Y=na.exclude(X)
summary(Y)
   Length     Class      Mode 
     9954 character character 

U=na.exclude(annotation$"SYMBOL")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "SYMBOL", value = c("SCYL3", "C1orf112",  : 
  replacement has 9954 rows, data has 16978
```

And I know that they replace all the genes with "NA" in their names as NA....

[image: X]

Does someone have an idea how to go through this?

For example, Number 11 and number 15 in this image are deleted when I use "na.omit" function ....

Comment: How do you read the original data.frame? Also, the image you posted does not show any `NA`s...

Comment: The image is "X" before I delete the NA. Number 11 and number 15 for example are deleted "DNAJC11" and "NADK", whereas they should not be since they are not NA

Comment: 'library(hgu95av2.db)
deb<-hgu95av2.db
keytypes(deb)
annotation = select(deb, keys = rownames(data), columns = c("SYMBOL","ENSEMBL"), keytype = "ENSEMBL")'

Comment: 1. Why `X=as.character(annotation$"SYMBOL")` and not `annotation$SYMBOL`

2. Why `unique (unlist (lapply (as.character(annotation$"SYMBOL"), function (x) which (is.na (x)))))` what is the intention behind this code? It seems overly complicated and will give only little information (1 if there are any `NA` or logical(0) if there are none)
I am still not sure if the NAs are in annotation or not.
Consider the following snippets: `na.exclude(c("daf", "dafa", "NA", "NADK", "DNAJ211", NA, NA, NA))`
`values <- c("daf", "dafa", "NA", "NADK", "DNAJ211", NA, NA, NA)``
`values[!is.na(values)]``

Comment: Also, this seems wierdly connected to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60064695/keep-values-in-data-frame-na-sodium-in-chemistry-as-is). Interestingly enough in 10+ years of R usage i have **never** come across this situation. That's why I am struggling to understand it. But I really want to help you if I can!

Comment: You are right. Your na.exclude() helped a lot

Comment: Actually, it was some rows further that was deleted and these rows were "NA"...

Comment: Thanks for your help !!! Sorry to mistaken it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set your `NA` values, you should use the code `df[df == "NA"] <- NA`. I used this with your test dataset and produced the desired results. You can then use the `na.omit()` function on your `df` to remove the now set `NA` data. I don't have a working code from you, so I will supply the outline of what your code should look like:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringAsFactors = FALSE)
df
     X1       X2
1   1    SCYL3
2   2 C1orf112
3   3      FGR
4   4      CFH
5   5    STPG1
6   6   NIPAL3
7   7      AK2
8   8    KDM1A
9   9    TTC22
10 10     ST7L
11 11  DNAJC11
12 12     FMO3
13 13     E2F2
14 14   CDK11A
15 15     NADK
16 16    CSDE1
17 17    MASP2
df[df == "NA"] <- NA
```

The `is.na(df)` function will return `FALSE` for all results. If you add any data which is `NA`, you can omit that row using the `na.omit(df)` now.